# Swift 4 - Populate tableview and pass array/dictionary data to detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'll start off by saying, I'm by far not a developer. I'm a designer and trying to put together a working prototype. Sorry if any what I'm asking seems vague but I've scoured YouTube tutorials and answers on here and still was stumped.

I have a view controller with a tableview inside of it. I'm trying to populate the table with an array of information. This is the first area I'm stuck at. I know how to populate a single data point to a cell, but not multiple pieces of data to a cell. The cell should show the beer's name, price and short description as shown in the attached image file. Here's the code that I have in the BeverageViewController currently. Also, the "ipsum lorem" text is additional descriptive text that I don't want shown but I do want it passed to the BeverageDetailsViewController to be displayed there if possible. I wasn't sure how to set up the prepareForSegue or performSegue to reference the selected row.

```
class BeveragesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var BeveragesTableView: UITableView!

// Data
let beverages = [
    ("Coke", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Sprite", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Powerade", "2.00", "20 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Blue Moon", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Budweiser", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Bud Light", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Corona", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Dos Equis", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Fat Tire", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Heineken", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Red Stripe", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem"),
    ("Stella Artois", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "Stella Artois Premium Lager"),
    ("Yuengling", "2.00", "12 fl oz", "ipsum lorem")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    BeveragesTableView.delegate = self
    BeveragesTableView.dataSource = self
}


//Populate Table 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return beverages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell  = BeveragesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let beverage = beverages[indexPath.row]



    return cell!

}
```

[image: UITableView]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a **model class** that holds information regarding data -:

```
import UIKit


class Videos:NSObject{

    var title:String?
    var thumbNailImageView : String?
    var channel : String?
    var numberOfView : Int?
    var duration : Int?

    init(title:String,thumbNailImageView:String,numberOfView:Int,duration:Int,channel:String) {
        self.channel = channel
        self.title = title
        self.thumbNailImageView = thumbNailImageView
        self.duration = duration
        self.numberOfView = numberOfView

    }
}
```

**Controller class-:**

Here we make array of type -> **model class**.After that append an `object` to an `array`.You can `fetch` your `data` from `server`, and execute a `loop` to input multiple `objects` information.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var model = [Videos]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Add object to array
        let object = Videos(title: "abc", thumbNailImageView: "adf", numberOfView: 1, duration: 2, channel: "cde");
        model.append(object);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath);
        cell.textLabel?.text = model[indexPath.row].title
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I have just given an example for workaround. You can create a custom cell class, place all required `outlets` as you want, and provide them `data` as shown in code.

No need set `dataSource` & `Delegate` in `viewdidLoad` if already connected from `storyboard`, and neither need to `register` a `cell` in `viewDidLoad` if using `storyboards`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it to work after going off of that example. One last thing, how am I able to put multiple items into that object? Currently I have: 

"//Add Object to array
        let object = Beverages(BeverageName: "Corona", BeveragePrice: "$2.00", BeverageSize: "12 fl oz", BeverageDesc: "lorem ipsum");
        "

Comment: @JasonTremain is all of your details coming from server?

Comment: No, I'm just hard coding it since it's a 'dummy app' just for the purpose of showing a prototype.  I figured out that I could just make multiple objects (object1 - object12) and append them. Just didn't know if there was a simpler way

Comment: @JasonTremain If it's just a prototype i guess showing different data on each cell might not be important. So what you can do to make it simpler is just execute a loop. For ex-: place that 2 lines in  loop and if loops runs 10 times, then 10 objects will be appended, but with similar details, or if you want a little change , you can interpolate index values with actual values.

Comment: @Downvoter please give reason as well, so I can improve my mistakes.Thanks